# ACCESS VBA Preventing duplicate value creation based on two criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have a listbox which gets populated from an other listbox1 . The user selects the data from the listbox and clicks on button which results in the data being enetered in the table. I have one problem that is i dont want the same values being enterd in the table again that is

One fiels is an ID  and the other field is a Text value and only when both the values are equla I  want a message box to pop up saying a duplicate value is created.

can someone help me on this?

Comment: Try using **[DlookUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dlookup-method-access)**. When the user clicks the button, check with DlookUp if the value already exists in the table, and then do whatever you need if it's true or false.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to split this process into two sections - checking for duplications, then adding to the table. You can check using the following, which compares the listbox to the textbox:

`Dim text As String`
`Dim i As Integer`

`If me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = 0  'only one selection
    if me.ListBox1.Value = me.textbox1.value
        msgbox "Multiple Values. Please try again", vbOkOnly
        End
    end if
elseif 'multiple selections
    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i)=me.textbox1.value Then 
            msgbox "Multiple Values. Please try again", vbOkOnly
            End
        End If
    Next i
end if`

'now add rows to table